# How come the redis-benchmark command is not following the redis protocol?

Tags: tcp, go, redis

I was reading in directly from a tcp connection after running the `redis-benchmark` command and as far as I can tell, `redis-benchmark` is NOT following the redis protocol.

The [redis protocol](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) is as stated in its website:

> The way RESP is used in Redis as a request-response protocol is the
>   following:
>
> - Clients send commands to a Redis server as a RESP Array of Bulk    Strings.
> - The server replies with one of the RESP types according to    the command implementation.

Meaning that a correct client implementation must always send **RESP arrays of bulk strings.**

If that is true, then, anything that does not start with a * is considered a syntax error (since its not an RESP array).

Thus, if one were to send a ping command to a redis-server, then it must be sent as a resp array of length 1 with 1 bulk string containing the word ping. For example:

> "*1\r\n$4\r\nPING\r\n"

However, whenever I listen directly to the redis-benchmark command and read its tcp connection I get instead:

> "PING\r\n"

which does **not** follow the redis protocol. Is that a bug or is there something implied in the redis protocol that makes pings special? As far as I could tell I couldn't find anything that said that pings were special, nor that length 1 commands were special. Does someone know whats going on?

To see reproduce these results yourself you can copy [my code](http://play.golang.org/p/smEp254J5n) to inspect it directly:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    RedisBenchmark()
}

func RedisBenchmark() {
    url := "127.0.0.1:6379"
    fmt.Println("listen: ", url)
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", url) //announces on local network
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept() //waits and returns the next connection to the listener
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        tcpConn := conn.(*net.TCPConn)
        go HandleConnection(tcpConn)
    }
}

func HandleConnection(tcpConn *net.TCPConn) {
    b := make([]byte, 256) //TODO how much should I read at a time?
    n, err := tcpConn.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("n: ", n)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("+++++> raw input string(b): %q\n", string(b))
    msg := string(b[:n])
    fmt.Printf("+++++> raw input msg: %q\n", msg)
}
```

and run it using go with:

`go run main.go`

followed on a different terminal (or tmux pane):

`redis-benchmark`

for all the test or if you only want to run ping with 1 client:

redis-benchmark -c 1 -t ping -n 1

you can see the details of how I am running it with the flags at: http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called an inline command. Check the [Inline Commands](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) section of the Redis Protocol article.

Comment: Is there anything else I should know when it stops following the protocol I specified in my question?

Comment: I think everything is specified in that document, but feel free to ask here or in the mailing list if you come across something strange.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the code for handling inline commands is as efficient as the code for commands that start with '*'. As an example, I found for my REDIS server that sending "*1\r\n$4\r\nPING\r\n" is about 5-6% faster than sending "PING\r\n". Not a significant difference but interesting to anyone that may have thought using inline commands might somehow be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the source code to find out the differences between inline command and **RESP**.

```
readQueryFromClient
|-->  if command begins with * --> processInlineBuffer()process it as RESP
|
|-->  if command not begins with * --> processMultibulkBuffer()：process it as inline command
```

**RESP** is a more efficent way to parse the command for the Redis Server